# Executing the next command bound to the same key

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

Is it possible to write an `execute-next-command` function that calls the command that would have been called if the current binding was not active?

For example, `RET` is bound to `newline` by default.  Let's say that I bind `RET` to `my-command`. In some cases, `my-command` should execute whatever would have been executed for `RET` if I hadn't bound it to `my-command`.  I could save the old binding before rebinding `RET`, but I would rather avoid that.

EDIT: There is the `key-binding` function, but it doesn't let you find the next binding.

Answer (score 4):

It's doable with minor modes. Suppose you have `my-minor-mode` active in an org-mode buffer.  And you have:

```
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-RET") #'save-buffer)
```

You could call the old <kbd>RET</kbd> binding in org-mode with:

```
(call-interactively
 (lookup-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-RET")))
```

Comment: This requires you figure out what other mode was the last to make a binding for that key.

Comment: You could let-bind `my-minor-mode` to `nil` and use `key-binding` instead, which checks all active maps, not just the one you pass in.